# page.clipRect causes page.render() to hang

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have this script for taking screenshots with PhantomJS:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open('https://github.com', function() {
    page.viewportSize = { width: 320, height: 600 };
    page.render('e:\\Screenshots\\test.png');
    phantom.exit();
```

It works fine but I want to set the height of the viewport as it's currently the entire pages height.

The documentation says to use page.clipRect : http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

But the below code doesn't work, it just hangs and never makes the screenshot:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open('https://github.com', function() {
    page.viewportSize = { width: 320, height: 600 };
    page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 320 height: 600 };
    page.render('e:\\Screenshots\\test.png');
    phantom.exit();
```

I get no error, just nothing happens and input stalls.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a plain old typo:

```
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 320 height: 600 };
```

should be

```
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 320, height: 600 };
                                             ^
```

But why would PhantomJS just hang there silently? There's a bug in v2 because of which errors won't show, so for now I use v1.9.8 to find syntax errors.

Comment: Ahh thanks, can't believe I didn't notice that.  Great tip on 1.9.8, I'll be doing the same from now on.